# Blender parametric modeling !help!

Tags: python, stl

I have been trying to define a set of parameters that I can change and iterate over to make a number of different blobs or shapes depending on the parameters.

The scrip is as follows:

```py
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Vector

while bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[0], do_unlink=True)

# Define the parametric functions with weights

def sin_func(x, y, z, w):
    return w * math.sin(x), w * math.sin(y), w * math.sin(z)

def cos_func(x, y, z, w):
    return w * math.cos(x), w * math.cos(y), w * math.cos(z)

def exp_func(x, y, z, w):
    return w * math.exp(x), w * math.exp(y), w * math.exp(z)

def tan_func(x, y, z, w):
    return w * math.tan(x), w * math.tan(y), w * math.tan(z)

def sqr_func(x, y, z, w):
    return w * (x**2), w * (y**2), w * (z**2)

# Define the arrays and weights for each function

arrays = [[sin_func, [1, 1, 1]], [cos_func, [2, 2, 2]], [exp_func, [3, 3, 3]], [tan_func, [4, 4, 4]], [sqr_func, [5, 5, 5]]]

# Set the number of vertices and the size of the bounding box

num_verts = 200
box_size = 4.0

# Create the mesh data

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('BlobMesh')

# Create the vertices

verts = []
for i in range(num_verts):
    x = (2*box_size)*(i/num_verts) - box_size
    for j in range(num_verts):
        y = (2*box_size)*(j/num_verts) - box_size
        for k in range(num_verts):
            z = (2*box_size)*(k/num_verts) - box_size
            weighted_sum = Vector((0, 0, 0))
            for func, weights in arrays:
                for j in range(3):
                    weighted_sum += Vector(func(x, y, z, weights[j])) * weights[j]
            verts.append(weighted_sum)

# Create the edges

edges = []
for i in range(num_verts-1):
    for j in range(num_verts-1):
        for k in range(num_verts-1):
            v1 = i*num_verts*num_verts + j*num_verts + k
            v2 = v1 + 1
            v3 = v1 + num_verts
            v4 = v2 + num_verts
            edges.extend([(v1, v2), (v1, v3), (v2, v4), (v3, v4), (v1, v4), (v2, v3)])

#Create the faces

faces = []
for i in range(num_verts-1):
    for j in range(num_verts-1):
        for k in range(num_verts-1):
            v1 = i*num_verts*num_verts + j*num_verts + k
            v2 = v1 + 1
            v3 = v1 + num_verts
            v4 = v2 + num_verts
            v5 = v1 + num_verts*num_verts
            v6 = v2 + num_verts*num_verts
            v7 = v3 + num_verts*num_verts
            v8 = v4 + num_verts*num_verts
            faces.extend([(v1, v2, v4, v3), (v5, v6, v8, v7), (v1, v3, v7, v5),
            (v2, v4, v8, v6), (v1, v2, v6, v5), (v3, v4, v8, v7)])

#Create the mesh object

mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('BlobObject', mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)


#Deselect all objects

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#Select the blob object and make it active

obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

#Apply scale and rotation to the object

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=True)

#Set the origin of the object to its center

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS')

#Export the object to an STL file again

bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath="blob.stl", check_existing=False, use_mesh_modifiers=True)
```

However, the resulting STL file doesn't have anything in it after taking like 20 mins to run. I can open the file in Solidworks but there isn't anything there.

Can someone help point out where im going wrong? The latter most part

Comment: Have your exported successfully any collection of objects not created by your script?  Do you have a valid selection in the Blender UI?  Have you consider a smaller test where ...num_verts = 4?  For testing you may want to separate the lengthy creation as opposed to export.

Comment: Are you asking about the time consumption of the Script or not?

Comment: It would be way more useful for you to choose a title that reflects the content of the question better than including meaningless text like "!help!". All questions here are asking for help - this adds nothing, just gets in the way as noise. If you choose a good title it may attract more people who might be able to help.

Comment: I gueses the best thing I can do is try to clarify. I am not using the blender gui. But certainly can if needed. I guess I just don't see many guide on have to make an object with parametric functions in an efficient manner. I believe what I am doing is possibly the right way to do it. But I'm VERY new to blender as in this week.

Comment: I am then going to eventually use that script in a bpy module in python to iterate over different parametric function inputs to generate 2 arbitrary but different objects. Sorry if I suck at posts I'm a super introvert

Answer (score 0):

When I set the filepath as "blob.stl" I get "Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'blob.stl'" . However, if I change the filepath to something like "C:\Users\yourUsername\Desktop\blob.stl" , I'm then able to see the stl file. I don't have Solidworks, but I downloaded FreeCAD and I was able to open the stl file with ease. (can also import .stl in Blender, but thought I'd try external CAD):

[image]

and the above shape matches what the script made in blender:

[image]

I chose for num_verts to equal 10 for this. Also, I'm not gonna make the assumption that this shape is incorrect, but it's very large, chaotic, and not what I imagine a "blob" to be shaped like. Maybe there're some math logic mistakes?

Comment: Ok thanks that actually helped a lot!